# How to set up local development environment for web application that uses OpenID connect?

Tags: security, testing, oauth, single-sign-on, development-environment

I would like some advice on how local development should work when developing a web application that uses OpenID connect for authentication.

- Should I really have a separate OpenID provider set up to redirect back to http://localhost:8000 (or whatever) so that logins work on developers' machines?
- What about for integration tests that run on the CI?
- Or, should I fall back to a secondary authentication method during local development (which seems to violate the 12 factor app dev/prod parity)?
- Or, should I stub out authentication altogether everywhere except for prod?